# $.parseJSON выбивает ошибку в коде, хотя в консоли все работает

Tags: jquery, json, javascript

Сервер присылает строку:

```
["ok",{"url":"05. You\'re my medicine.mp3","size":10214192,"artist":"Gare Du Nord","title":"You\'re my medicine","duration":"4:15","year":"2010","genre":"Jazz","num":"05"}]
```

Я её сразу пропускаю через $.parseJSON и при этом получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '

Но когда я в консоли (Google Chrome) запускаю этот код все прекрасно работает.
Почему так?

Comment: экранирование кавычки уберите.
http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: @Yura Ivanov а что делать если попадется не ' а " ?

Comment: а вы вручную собираете json? используйте json_encode, который выдает валидный json. если будет ", то она будет экранирована, а вот одинарная ' не экранируется.

Comment: А если JSON.parse(str) ?

Comment: @dimka3210, загляните в исходники $.parseJSON, по большому счету это одно и то же.